How do I get ESLint 9 to work with pug templates?
My stack consists of Pug templates, JS (Jquery), yaml and stylus files. I am struggling to get ESLint to work with Pug. I have installed the eslint-plugin-pug and added it to the plugins in the eslint config file, however it does not seem to work on the script parts of the pug files.
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import prettierPluginRecommended from 'eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended';
import pugPlugin from 'eslint-plugin-pug';

export default [
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ['**/*.js'],
    languageOptions: {
      sourceType: 'script',
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.jquery,
      },
    },
    rules: {
      'no-use-before-define': [
        'error',
        {
          functions: false,
          variables: true,
        },
      ],

      'no-unused-vars': 'warn',
      'no-undef': 'warn',
      'no-redeclare': 'warn',
      'no-console': 'warn',
      'no-duplicate-imports': 'error',
      'no-template-curly-in-string': 'error',
      'no-empty-function': 'error',
      'no-lonely-if': 'error',
      'no-magic-numbers': 'error',
      'no-var': 'error',

      'func-style': ['error', 'declaration'],
      'vars-on-top': 'error',
      'prefer-const': 'error',
      'require-await': 'error',

      'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
      'default-case': 'error',
      'capitalized-comments': ['error', 'always'],
      'new-cap': ['error', { newIsCap: true }],
      'max-depth': ['error', 3],

      eqeqeq: 'error',
      camelcase: 'error',
      yoda: ['error', 'never', { exceptRange: true }],
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.pug'],
    plugins: { pugPlugin },
  },
  prettierPluginRecommended,
];


  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.0",
    "@prettier/plugin-pug": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-pug": "^1.2.5",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "prettier-plugin-stylus": "^0.1.0"
  }

I tried downgrading eslint to v8 since v9 is not supported by the plugin, but that did not seem to work either.
Currently when I run npx eslint *.pug on a pug file, then it gives me
Parsing error: Unexpected token extends (since the specific pug template extends a general pug file.)
